# svg:not(:root) overflow hidden and CSS transforms in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, internet-explorer-9

It's common practice to have:

```
svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

In your reset.css or [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/64de79a543546eaba548eed9d2be20986857a0e8/README.md#svgnotroot) because of an SVG rendering issue in IE9 (that I have not actually observed myself). However, if you rotate an svg with this applied using `-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);` the SVG will disappear.

Viewing this jsfiddle in IE9:

https://jsfiddle.net/750r17hg/1/

You can see that by removing the `overflow: hidden` will make the icon appear..

My question is,what are the repercussions of removing this (as I have not seen the issue it is trying to fix) and whether there is anything else I can do to make the icon appear when rotated.

Comment: Just removed it myself because of this issue. Let's see what beasts rear their heads.

Comment: I haven't observed this bug either. My site uses SVG icons, and they all seem to be OK. If it's just for rotating or transforming SVGs, I'm happy enough just to get rid of the rule. It's causing other non-IE issues for me.